# ElasticSearch `contains` suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch

I have doc like

```
{name: "foo", tags: ["bar", "baz"]}
```

When I type `a` I want to suggest all `tag` that contains `a`(bar, and baz for above example), but not only start with `a` as [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html).

Which suggester should I use ?

Or how could I achieve similar functionality performance friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fork [term list plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist), and modify its implementations [here](https://github.com/jilen/elasticsearch-index-termlist)

It works well while number of term is small